# Chef Exec Rspec Error: uninitialized constant Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Security

Tags: chef-infra

I am writing a code to run a resource "windows_task" on a windows server. The "chef exec rspec" is throwing failures.

I am trying to run unit test on a resource 'windows_task' but getting the failures. Is there any solution or workaround for this. My workstation is a EC2 Linux server but trying to test a resource for Windows.

`recipes/default.rb`:

```
windiows_task 'client' do
  run_level :highest
  command 'ipconfig.exe'
  user 'SYSTEM'
  frequency :hourly
  frequency_modifier 20
end
```

`spec/unit/recipes/default_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'windows_test::default' do
  context 'when all attributes are default to windows' do
    let(:chef_run) do
      runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2012R2')
      runner.converge(described_recipe)
  end
  it 'converges successfully' do
     expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
  end
 end
 at_exit {ChefSpec::Coverage.report!}
end
```

Actual Result is a failure rather than getting success:

Failures:

```
   1) windows_test::default when all attributes are default to windows converges successfully.
   Failure/Error: expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error

   expected no Exception, got #<NameError: uninitialized contstant Chef::Win32::Security
   Did you mean? SecurityError> with backtrace:
     # /tmpchefspec20190704-../cookbooks.windows_test/recipes/dafault.rb:35:in `from file`
    ----
    ----
Finished in 0.73 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Answer (score 0):

since some information is missing from your post, it is hard to pinpoint exactly what's wrong, but seems like your are missing dependencies.

i would advise to revisit your `spec_helper` file to make sure that your `require()` [`chefspec`](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec) and [`chef`](https://github.com/chef/chef) rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to testing windows resource on linux.
You can find more information in this [chefspec github issue](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec/issues/952).

The fix that worked for me was:

```
stubs_for_resource('windows_task') do |res|
    allow(res).to receive(:user).and_return(nil)
end
```